# I am using CameSalesforcesourceConnector (version 3.18.x) of apache camel to consume pushtopic events from salesforce

Tags: apache-camel

I am getting following error

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:298)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:324)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:248)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Invalid type for bytes type: class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache
at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJson(JsonConverter.java:611)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJsonWithEnvelope(JsonConverter.java:550)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.fromConnectData(JsonConverter.java:304)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$2(WorkerSourceTask.java:298)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)

I used following config to create connector

{
"name": "camel_local_emea_dell_contact",
"config":{
"connector.class": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.salesforcesource.CamelSalesforcesourceSourceConnector",
"topics": "kafkaTopic",
"camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.loginUrl": "",
"camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.query": "",
"camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.topicName": "pushtopic",
"camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.clientId": "",
"camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.clientSecret": "",
"camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.userName": "",
"camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.password": "",
"camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.notifyForOperations": "ALL",
"camel.source.endpoint.rawPayload": "true"
}
}

connector download url  : **https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/next/reference/index.html**

Note : I tried providing value.converter and JosnConverter and ByteArrayConverter , and in both cases i got same error
marshal property also not working

Can anyone provide any solution for this , or there any other property that i can use .